# How to make hover data into currency in plotly?

Tags: python, hover, plotly

I'm using plotly to get get a bar chart with hover data on it, specifically putting the dollar sign in front of some of the data.

It's quite a long code, so I've just put the most important part causing the trouble below. I want the first 3 to have a dollar sign in front and the last 3 to not. Currently ':,.0f' works fine to format to 0dp but when I include the dollar sign and {} in '${:,.0f}' those data hover points say
%customdata[2]%${: ,0f}% instead of the correct value with the dollar sign.

If I use :,.0f for all of them it all works fine but I lose the dollar sign for the ones I want. I feel like this is something stupid but I can't find it.
Any help?

Thank You

```
hover_data = {('Total ' + str(y) + ' '  + str(x) + ' (Euros) ') :'${:,.0f}', 
                                 ('Average Player Value ') : '${:,.0f}' ,         
                                 ('Average Player Wage ') : '${:,.0f}' , 
                                 ('Total Players ') : ':,.0f', 
                                 ('Average Player Overall ') : ':,.0f' ,
                                 ('Average Player Potential ') : ':,.0f'}
```

Comment: Hi aquamad96, welcome on SO. Please have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve), Having a full mcve will improve the chance to get one or more answer.